# JPA discrim value not used when retrieving collection on none owning side

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table task which contains differnet types of tasks e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE TASK (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, TYPE INTEGER, TYPE_ID VARCHAR2);
```

I am trying to map this in JPA where I have a task object like this..

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, name = "TYPE")
public abstract class Task {
    @Id private Integer id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class FirstTask extends Task {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID")
    private Entity1 entity1;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class AnotherTask extends Task {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID")
    private Entity2 entity2;
}
```

I then have the tasks mapped to a collection on the other side..

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="entity1")
    private List<FirstTask> firstTasks;
    ...
}
```

When I try and retrieve the firstTasks on this side it doesn't use the discriminator value as part of the query only queries the task table for tasks with type ID equal to. I would have thought it would use type as well. Any ideas what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Why should it use the discriminator value? It doesn't need more than the foreign key

Comment: because its not unique, its unique on TYPE and TYPE_ID

Comment: But then your Primary Key must be TYPE and TYPE_ID and so must be your foreign key. If you map it with the compound key Hibernate will do what you want